# Bringing State Boundary closer to land using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS.

I downloaded a data from a website and tried uploading it to the base map plugin which would be OpenStreetMap.

However, the boundary is not close to the land.

For example, like this:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to bring the boundary closer to the land?

I have also used other base map plugins such as Google and Bing. It is still causing the same issue.

Comment: Maybe because the boundary IS in the water. You can look for the shoreline/landmass layer (easily available for Canada, not sure where to look for for the US)

Comment: Anyway to move the boundary back to the region??

Comment: You can look for a shoreline/landmass layer. Else you would need to manually edit your layer

Comment: @VivekChristy if you wouldn't be able to find a shoreline layer, finding water body boundaries should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Lakes and Reservoirs layer from Natural Earth Data.
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/

Load the lakes and reservoirs layer into QGIS.

Select the two Great Lakes that overlap the New York state boundary.

Use the Difference tool to subtract the lakes from the state polygon.

- Input layer: state boundary
- Difference layer: lakes and reservoirs layer

  - Check the box for "selected features only" under Difference layer (otherwise the tool will cut all lakes out of the state polygon, including, eg, the Finger Lakes)

[image]

If the boundary layer has fields such as area and perimeter, be aware that these values are no longer accurate.